Influxdb query to select last datapoint each day
I have a timeseries in InfluxDB which contains the energy (kWh) used and it resets every day at midnight. I would like to get energy consumption (kWh) for each day. No interpolation, mean values etc.
How can I make a query that gives me the last datapoint each day?
Or, even better, how can I make a query that gives me the value before each location where the derivative turns negative (=reset occurs)?

To get the last data point each day, try something like following SQL query:
SELECT last("energy") AS "daily_energy"
FROM "your_measurement"
WHERE time >= '2024-01-01T00:00:00Z' AND time < '2024-12-31T23:59:59Z'
GROUP BY time(1d)
For comparing value before "reset occurs" you need to look into "lag()"
